# как вывести всю колонку таблицы? SQLite, python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

есть таблица:

```
-------------------------
| id | name |  nickname |
-------------------------
| 1 | egor  | pythonist |
| 2 | nikita| other...  |
-------------------------
```

нужно вывести только все записи в колонке id

Comment: *нужно вывести только все записи в колонке id* Дык там одни голые числа - смысл? а так - ну `SELECT id FROM tablename;`

Comment: мне и нужны голые числа

Comment: Ну запрос я дал - получайте да выводите.